# Javascript gives wrong answer on multiplication 290.4*100 in every browser

Tags: javascript, math, browser

Why the multiplication 290.4*100 gives wrong answer 29039.999999999996?
[multiplication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAsNa.jpg)

Comment: It's not wrong, it's just the way it is ;) http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken